# How to retain position of ListView in FragmentPagerAdapter with ListFragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, fragment

I have three ListFragments in FragmentPagerAdapter. I am inflating views in OnCreateView of Fragment.
I am able to retain fragment instance so it doesn't create new in swipe. But on every swipe onCreateView is called and ListView lost it's position and shows list from 0th index.

How can I retain the position of ListView index in all three ListFragment.